# Connecting two motors

Tags: voltage, dc-motor

Basically i'm doing a small project where i'm using 2 dc motors on a bicycle as generators connected to a usb module to charge smart phones, is it possible to connect the motors together to generate the required voltage at a lower rpm.

Comment: You'll need to provide a bit more detail on your setup, what you've tried, circuits, etc. for a sensible answer. I assume you've got some sort of regulator circuit between the motor/generator(s) and the phone/module? or is the "usb module" a regulator? You could gear the motor to run faster, connect the motors in series, use a different motor, use a buck/boost regulator circuit to accept a wider range of voltages, etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to increase voltage by placing them in series.

The output generated can be seen as batteries. When batteries are placed in series the voltage stacks. When placed parallel the voltage stays the same but you can get a higher current from it.

Now if you want to charge a phone by USB you will need a steady 5 volt power. the easiest would be to use a simple 5V ldo so that you wont blow up the phone with a voltage that is too high.

Because some phones have a protection circuit to stop charging when an unstable charger is used, you will need Extra buffers.

An other option would be to use a booster circuit. this will boost the voltage to the required voltage. but you would still need the buffers. There are converters that can work with an input voltage of 1.8-15V and convert any of these to 5V. The output current is dependent on the input voltage/current

Comment: as long as the two machines rotate the same way - ie one rotor on the LEFT & the other on the RIGHT, direct drive (or same number of cogs/sprockets) would result in a short-circuit due to +ve and -ve generation

Answer (score 0):

You can connect two motors but it's probably better to use a boost regulator on one motor like this one: -

[image]

[image]

[Here](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/pololu-5v-boost-regulator?utm_source=google&utm_medium=googleshopping&utm_campaign=googlebase&gclid=CJ-znrfnmsICFSIYwwodFEgAzw) is the site for it. This device operates from an input voltage as low as 0.8 volts and is rated for a maximum nominal input voltage of 5V so, if your motors-turned generators produce more than 5V you'd be looking for a different solution such as one that involves a low-drop-out buck regulator interfacing between generator and booster. [Here](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/d24v3f5-5v-regulator) is a possible option to consider - it works from a voltage as high as 42 volts to produce 5V.

Or go all out for the boost/buck device [here](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/s7v7f5-5v-regulator) - it works from 2.7 volts to over 11 volts - maybe this is enough. Plenty of choices really.

Is this better than using two motors - I think so but beware of reversing the generator - it will produce negative voltages and damage stuff.